# What should I do when I am using Dijkstra's Algorithm and there is multiple self loop for one vertex?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I know the parallel edges, which have max weights, should be removed, and self loops also be removed to find the shortest path.

But what if there are multiple self loops for a vertex and their weights are varied?

Suppose **A** vertex has 3 self loop, their weights are --> 4,5,1

Which should I remove or the all 3 should be removed?

Answer (score 2):

All three, for the shortest path you can ignore self-loops as long as they are non-negative (where Dijkstra would not work anymore anyways). A loop makes any path thus longer.